# Create a Custom 404 View for ONE Specific Generic View

Tags: python, django

**This is not a duplicate question as what it's attempting is different from usinng `handler404`.**

Unfortunately, some moderators marked this question as a duplicate while it really isn't. :(

**Note: I don't mean changing the `handler404` for the entire project.** I only want to override the 404 response for **one specific generic view** not the entire project.

For instance, when users visits this specific view, if 404 occurs, they will be shown a special 404 page. For any other views, the 404 response remains default.

Comment: Please show the view.

Comment: @Alasdair It's just a plain TemplateView, not very relevant. Though, I don't think it's possible to set a custom 404 view for only one specific view at this point.

Comment: One option is to modify the view to catch the the Http404 exception, and return the custom 404 response. If you don't show an example view, then you're asking users to write one for you, so you're less likely to get an answer. The duplicate target also seems to be a solution -- return a custom 404 response for your view, and render the default 404 template for all other requests.

Comment: @Alasdair Yeah the catch-and-redirect approach maybe a solution. Though, the 'duplicate' answer is not a solution here since it just replaces the default 404 view for the entire project.

Comment: Yes, it replaces the default 404 for the entire project, but if your custom 404 handler renders '404.html' for all other views, then the result is the same as before.

Comment: @Alasdair Yeah that's what I mean.